# how to loop over nested json?

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to retreive some JSON from a server which looks like the following

```
json  =  {"posts":[{
      "post":{
        "title" : "foo", 
            }
      },
      {
      "post":{
        "title" : "bar", 
            }
      },
]}
```

And I am trying to loop over like

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
    console.log(obj.posts.post.title); 
}
```

Which doesn't work.

And I've tried

```
var totalMessages = Object.keys(json.posts).length;

for(var i = 0; i < totalMessages; i++) {
        console.log(json.posts.post.title); 
    }
```

Which also doesn't work

How can I loop through the above json and log the titles?

Thanks

Comment: `json` is an object, not an array, it doesn't have `length`. The array is `json.posts`, loop over that.

Comment: `for(let post of json.posts) console.log(post.title)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
json  =  {
     "posts":[{
     "post":{
        "title" : "foo", 
            }
      },{
      "post":{
        "title" : "bar", 
            }
      },
]}

json.posts.forEach(postContainer => { 
     let post = postContainer.post;
     console.log(post.title); 
});
```

You're forgetting that `posts` is an array of unnamed objects.
Those unnamed objects have a property called post.
That property contains the post info you need.
You only need to go "one layer deeper"

Basically, your structure is, `json.posts[arrayindex].post.title`, in your code you assumed post was at the position of `arrayIndex`, and `title` at the position of `post`.